# Using yaml to store static data

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yaml file with a bunch of static data, let's say:

```
Pets\ and\ names
    Cats: ['Cat Name 1','Cat Name 2']
    Dogs: ['Dog Name 1','Dog Name 2']
```

I want to do a look up by pet type, so if a user wants to look at the names of all the cats, they pass me "cats" and I return to them a list of cat names.

But I can't figure out how to do this.

I read a couple of articles on how to do this, but it seems like I have to create a PetsAndNames object, then define all the pets I have in this object? Is there a workaround to this?

Do I even need to create a pojo?

Answer (score 0):

What about having it like this ?

```yaml
Pets:
 cats:
   - Cat Name 1
   - Cat Name 2
 dogs:
   - Dog Name 1
   - Dog Name 2
```

Later in your java Pojo:

```java
class Pets {
  List<String> cats;
  List<String> dogs;
}
```

I would recommend using json for static data rather then yaml file but it is still your choice.

Comment: I think both mean the same thing, but the issue is I have a lot of pets, it's a really long list

Comment: @Spider If this is immutable list and don't plan to update it, use json file otherwise go with some kind of db. What do you mean by long list ? (give us some numbers)

Comment: 200 pets and several names for each one

Comment: @Spider That is not too much , what bother you, just prepare the file and use it.

Comment: I guess I can convert my list of pets into an actual list